# How to execute a request in a PHP file from a server using Sencha Touch 2

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I coded a mobile application which presents some articles using Sencha Touch 2 Framework.
I use a MySQL database in localhost with Wamp server. The application works perfectly. Now I want to deploy my database management from an other server with a specific IP address but I have the following message in the JS console on Google Chrome :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load
http://<ip_address>:[port]/[path_to_services_directory]/ArticleListService.php?action=read&_dc=1372077575445&keyword=&page=1&start=0&limit=25. Origin http://localhost is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Nevertheless, I passed in my database configuration good informations (host, db_name, password, etc.).

Here's my ArticleListStore.js definition :

```
Ext.define("LargusDuMobile.store.ArticleListStore", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Store",
    initialize: function () {

    },
    requires: ["LargusDuMobile.model.ArticleModel"],
    config: {
    model: "LargusDuMobile.model.ArticleModel",
    proxy: {
        type: "ajax",
        api: {
            read: http://<ip_address>:<port>/<path_to_services_directory>/ArticleListService.php?action=read"
         },
        extraParams: {
            keyword: ""
        },
        reader: {
            type: "json",
            rootProperty: "articles_list",
            totalProperty: "total"
        }
    },
        autoLoad: true
    }
});
```

My ArticleListService.php code :

```
<?php

include_once "../db/DummyDbManager.php";
include_once "../db/PDODbManager.php";
include_once "AbstractService.php";

class ArticleListService extends AbstractService
{
    //Properties

    private $m_name = NULL;
    private $m_dbManager = NULL;
    private $m_callback = NULL;

    //Singleton instance

    static private $m_instance = NULL;

    //Initialization

    private function __construct(&$dbManager)
    {
        $this->m_dbManager = $dbManager;
        $this->m_name = get_class($this);
    }

    //Singleton pattern

    static public function getSingleton($dbManager)
    {
        if (self::$m_instance == NULL)
            self::$m_instance = new ArticleListService($dbManager);
        return (self::$m_instance);
    }

    //Read the 15 most recent articles

    public function read(array &$ref_result)
    {
        $ref_result = array("articles_list" => array(), "total" => 0);

        $query = "SELECT a.id, a.title, a.contents, a.main_image FROM argus_articles a"
            . " WHERE a.contents NOT LIKE '%<iframe%' ORDER BY a.id DESC LIMIT 15 OFFSET 200";
        $dbresult = $this->m_dbManager->query($query);

        while ($row = $this->m_dbManager->fetch($dbresult)) {

            array_push($ref_result["articles_list"], array(
                "id" => $row["id"],
                "title" => addslashes((string)$row["title"]),
                "contents" => (string)$row["contents"],
                "main_image" => (string)$row["main_image"]));
        }
        $ref_result["total"] = $this->m_dbManager->affectedRows();
        $this->m_dbManager->disconnect();
    }

    //Create a new record

    public function create(array &$ref_result)
    {

    }

    //Update a specific record

    public function update(array &$ref_result)
    {

    }

    //Destroy a specific record

    public function destroy(array &$ref_result)
    {

    }

    //Initialize action dispatcher function pointer

    public function initialize_action_dispatcher(&$action_map)
    {
        $action_map = array("read" => "read", "create" => "create",
            "update" => "update", "destroy" => "destroy");
    }

    //Request launcher

    public function launch()
    {
        $this->m_dbManager->connect();

        if (isset($_REQUEST["action"])) {

            $action_dispatcher = array();
            $this->initialize_action_dispatcher($action_dispatcher);

            $html_result = array();
            $this->m_callback = $action_dispatcher[$_REQUEST["action"]];

            call_user_func_array($this->m_name . '::' . $this->m_callback, array(&$html_result));
        }
        header("Content-Type: application/x-json");
        $json_result = json_encode($html_result);
        echo $json_result;
    }
}

//Entry point

function main()
{
    $configFile = "../config/config.xml";
    $dbManager = new PDODbManager($configFile);
    $blogService = ArticleListService::getSingleton($dbManager);
    $blogService->launch();
}

main();

?>
```

I think the problem comes from the fact that I execute my application from Wamp server and I want to execute external PHP files on another one (so a cross-domain problem). Does anyone already had this problem ?
Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that your problem comes from trying to execute php files on a different server than where your app is running.  The only solution to this is to use a JSON-P proxy: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.JsonP

One other possible solution is that if you are making a native app with Sencha Touch, you can use something like PhoneGap (Cordova) to allow for cross-domain requests like this.

Comment: Ok I'll try to use this. Thanks for your answer. Bye.